# Bind event to multiple widgits in list

Tags: python, tkinter, events, combobox

I try to make multiple comboboxes performe the same command when being used - they should simutanously change values when one is used. I appended all of them to lists and wrote this code, which is not working.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
root = tk.Tk()

comboboxes=[]
entries=[]
values=['a', 'b', 'c']
c=ttk.Combobox(root,values=values)
c2=ttk.Combobox(root,values=values)
comboboxes.append(c)
comboboxes.append(c2)
e1 = Entry(root, bd=3)
e2 = Entry(root, bd=3)
entries.append(e1)
entries.append(e2)
for i in range(len(comboboxes)):
    comboboxes[i].pack()
    entries[i].pack()


for i in range(len(comboboxes)):    
    for i in range(len(comboboxes)):
      def combo(event):
        for i in range(len(comboboxes)):
            X=  str(comboboxes[i].get()) 
            if X==("a"):
                A=3
            elif X==("b"):
                A=2
            elif X==("c"):
                A=1

            entries[i].delete(0, 'end')
            entries[i].insert(END, A )
    comboboxes[i].bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', combo )
root.mainloop()
```

I'd be very grateful for help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by *"not working"*? Also your code has indentation issue.

Comment: create minimal working code so we could run it and see problem.

Comment: I updated it. It was to long as a comment. Thank you. If you use the second one first, and error appears.

Comment: What is the error? Please include that information in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow.

It is code like this which should remind us all that in a production environment we often must work with legacy code which we do not have the luxury of rewriting.  I don't say that to be hurtful as you're obviously new to both Python and TKinter, I just think it's worth noting as it's something which hobby programmers, or professionals who've never had to work in a corporate environment, don't often think about.

In the spirit of having said that, this is *not* how I would have approached this problem, but I've tried to "fix" the code *without* completely rewriting it.  In the end it was probably as much work to modify as it would have been to rewrite.

I've commented out your code that I "removed" to make it easier for you to compare your original code to what I've changed.  I've marked the lines that I've added, modified, or moved.

I also changed the `values` list to a dictionary to get rid of all the `if` statements.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

###############
# I've moved this entire block of code to the top so that combo() is
#   recognized before anything else runs.
###############
#for i in range(len(comboboxes)):    
#    for i in range(len(comboboxes)):
def combo(event):
    for i in range(len(comboboxes)):
        if comboboxes[i] == event.widget:   ### NEW LINE ###
            for j in range(len(entries)):   ### MODIFIED ###
                entries[j].delete(0,'end')  ### MODIFIED ###
                entries[j].insert(0, values[comboboxes[i].get()]) ### NEW LINE ###
        # X=  str(comboboxes[i].get()) 
            # if X==("a"):
                # A=3
            # elif X==("b"):
                # A=2
            # elif X==("c"):
                # A=1
            # entries[i].insert(END, A )


root = tk.Tk()

comboboxes=[]
entries=[]
values = {'a':3, 'b':2, 'c':1} ### NEW LINE ###
#values=['a', 'b', 'c']
c=ttk.Combobox(root,values=list(values.keys()))     ### MODIFIED ###
c2=ttk.Combobox(root,values=list(values.keys()))    ### MODIFIED ###
comboboxes.append(c)
comboboxes.append(c2)
e1 = Entry(root, bd=3)
e2 = Entry(root, bd=3)
entries.append(e1)
entries.append(e2)
for i in range(len(comboboxes)):
    comboboxes[i].pack()
    comboboxes[i].bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', combo) ### MOVED ###
    entries[i].pack()


root.mainloop()
```

As an additional note I want to point out that the only place you use `c`, `c2`, `e1`, and `e2` are for the purposes of adding them to lists.  You can do this without using variable names:

```
comboboxes.append(ttk.Combobox(root,values=list(values.keys())))
comboboxes.append(ttk.Combobox(root,values=list(values.keys())))
entries.append(Entry(root, bd=3))
entries.append(Entry(root, bd=3))
```

Comment: That's great!  Say... if it worked for you could you mark this as the accepted answer?  I'd appreciate it.  Take care.